# Is it possible to find out the number of function parameters without documentation?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, calling-convention

As far as I'm concerned x64 calling convention passes the first 4 arguments to a function in registers. But what if my function only has 2 arguments? What will be placed in those 2 spare registers? And how do I find out how many arguments this function has (without reading the documentation)?

Comment: *"(without reading the documentation..."* Why not just read the documentation, as it is the best way to find out?

Comment: *What will be placed in those 2 spare registers?* - They're just like any other volatile (call-clobbered) registers in that case; look at compiler output.  (e.g. https://godbolt.org/, using MSVC since it seems you're talking about the Windows x64 calling convention, not x86-64 System V.) So same thing as all the other registers, and stack slots in memory that don't hold args either: whatever "garbage" the caller wants to leave there.

Comment: As for reverse-engineering, yeah, given the asm for a caller and/or a callee, you can often make a good guess at how many args are being passed.  A callee could ignore args, so seeing a call-site is often more informative.

Comment: In C++, you can find out how many parameters a function has by looking at the C++ source itself, the prototype.  Unlike hand-written source where that would be implicit in the code, and thus be something that comments would normally mention, if that's what you mean by documentation?

Comment: Well, my task is to print first 4 string parameters of a random function of kernel32 after it's been hooked. I don't know in advance which function will be chosen, so documentation is not an option.

Comment: There is nothing to tell you what the parameters of an undocumented function are. You can try to infer their meaning from context, but that's a job for human brains. not computers. What is the person who gave you that task going to do with the information anyway?

Comment: "Well, my task is to print first 4 string parameters of a random function of kernel32 after it's been hooked. I don't know in advance which function will be chosen" -- Then your only option is to unconditionally output all four parameters. You don't know what function will be called, so there's no way you can interpret the parameters beyond outputting them as 64-bit unsigned values.